# Does VB.NET and Visual Studio 2010 support multiline anonymous method?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I found that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671631/does-vb-net-have-anonymous-functions) was asked and answered before VS2010 was actually released.

They say that

> VB9 has only single-line anonymous
>   functions. We're adding full statement
>   and multi-line lambdas in VB10.

But I tried to add this code

```
 Dim test2 = Function(t1 As T, t2 As T) (
 Dim val1 As IComparable = DirectCast(prop.GetValue(t1), IComparable)
 Dim val2 As IComparable = DirectCast(prop.GetValue(t2), IComparable)
 Return val1.CompareTo(val2)
 )
```

to a .NET Framework 4.0 project in Visual Studio 2010 and it does not compile.

Do you now if this feature is really implemented and what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you are only missing your 'End Function' line.  Try this:

```
 Dim test2 = (Function(t1 As T, t2 As T)
 Dim val1 As IComparable = DirectCast(prop.GetValue(t1), IComparable)
 Dim val2 As IComparable = DirectCast(prop.GetValue(t2), IComparable)
 Return val1.CompareTo(val2)
 End Function)
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! Sorry for the silly question, probably is too hot today in the office :D.

Comment: Haha!  Not silly at all!  I ran into the exact same problem not one week ago.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `End Function` and you are trying to enclose the function body in parenthesis, which is wrong. This should work:

```
Dim test2 = Function(t1 As T, t2 As T)
    Dim val1 As IComparable = DirectCast(prop.GetValue(t1), IComparable)
    Dim val2 As IComparable = DirectCast(prop.GetValue(t2), IComparable)
    Return val1.CompareTo(val2)
End Function
```

This feature is documented here:

- [Lambda Expressions (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Here is something you might find useful. Note how the method declared is instantly invoked.

```
Dim food = New With {
    .ID = 1,
    .Name = "Carrot",
    .Type = (
        Function(name As String)
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) Then Return String.Empty

            Select Case name.ToLower()
                Case "apple", "tomato": Return "Fruit"
                Case "potato": Return "Vegetable"
            End Select

            Return "Meat"
        End Function
    )(.Name)
}
Dim type = food.Type
```