# anonymous functions in vb (not working in older .net)

Tags: vb.net, anonymous-function

How do you rewrite the following to work in older vb.net environments? This is not working with build machine?

Just create a function that takes in two AuctionInfos returns an integer? Then do the addressof thang?

```
 tempItems.Sort(
            Function(aInfo1 As AuctionInfo, aInfo2 As AuctionInfo)
                Return aInfo1.StartTime.CompareTo(aInfo2.StartTime)
            End Function)
```

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get a compile-time error or a runtime exception? Does your `tempItems` list contain any `null` (`Nothing`) values?

Comment: works fine.. does not build on build machine with older .net

Comment: Which "older" .NET? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671631/does-vb-net-have-anonymous-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work...

```
    tempItems.Sort(AddressOf AuctionSorter)


Public Shared Function AuctionSorter(aInfo1 As AuctionInfo, aInfo2 As AuctionInfo) As Integer
    Return aInfo1.StartTime.CompareTo(aInfo2.StartTime)
End Function
```