# Using lambda expressions in .net 2.0 with anonymous methods

Tags: vb.net, syntax, lambda

**This question is related to Visual Basic .NET 2010**

Okay so I use lambda expressions in my code, and I need to compile it to target the 2.0 version of the .net framework. I won't be able to use LINQ since it's 3.0 and above, but I've head that there's a possibility to use anonymous methods in the code to allow some lambda expressions.

So say that I'm using code such as:

```
AsyncOperation.Post(Sub(x) Something(x), Nothing)
```

What would the anonymous method look like to support such syntax?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does VB.NET have anonymous functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/671631/50447)

Comment: @RowlandShaw The question isn't about wether VB.NET __has__ anonymous functions or not.

Comment: So what do you want to know? (Given the other question has an example of syntax)

Comment: @RowlandShaw I want to know how to create an anonymous method that enables me to use lambda syntax such as in the example code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# supports both anonymous methods and lambda expressions.  Generally speaking, they both serve the same kind of purpose, but their syntax, and the way that they work, are different.  VB.NET, on the other hand, only supports lambda expressions.  It does not support anything equivalent to C#'s anonymous methods.  However, since VB.NET's syntax for lambda expressions more closely resemble C#'s syntax for anonymous methods, it is not uncommon for people to mistakenly refer to them as "anonymous methods" in VB.NET, even though they are, in reality, lambda expressions.

Lambda expressions are not inherently supported by MSIL.  They are supported by the VB.NET compiler which builds the necessary MSIL code to accomplish the desired task.  Therefore, even though lambda expressions were not added until the 3.5 version of the VB.NET compiler, the 3.5 version of the framework is not required to run the MSIL code that was compiled from lambda expressions.  What that means is, as long as you are compiling your VB.NET code  using a 3.5 or later version of the compiler, you can target the 2.0 version of the framework even with lambda expressions.

Since Visual Studio always uses the highest version compiler, when you are using Visual Studio 2010, it will use the 3.5 version compiler, even when you are targeting earlier versions of the framework.  The up-shot of all of this is that when you use Visual Studio 2010 (or later), you can use things like lambda expressions and auto-properties even when you are targeting the 2.0 framework.

Comment: I'm trying to compile my code using the CodeDOM compiler. How do I change the compiler version in that?

Comment: The CodeDOM compiler is part of the .NET framework, so it is the same version as whichever version of the framework that you are compiling.  If your project, which uses CodeDOM, targets the 2.0 framework, then it will compile using the 2.0 compiler.  If you need it to compile using 3.5, then you will need to target the 3.5 framework.

Comment: The thing is, I need to compile to target the 2.0 version of the framework while using lambda syntax which only compiles for me using the 4.0 framework.

Comment: Your compiler project can target the 4.0 framework and have it just add references to the older 2.0 framework libraries when it builds the output assembly.

Comment: Okay, I compiled it to target the 4.0 framework and only referenced 2.0 assemblies. Now how can I check if the output binary requires 2.0 or 4.0 to run?

Comment: I don't know of anyway besides simply attempting to run it on a machine that only has the 2.0 framework installed.  If there's a fancier way to do it, I'm not aware of it.